# Showing infinite sum of integrals equals the integral of the absolute value

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series

Assume that $f\in L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$. Show that 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=-n^2}^{n^2}\left|\int_{k/n}^{(k+1)/n}f(x)dx \right|=\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f(x)|dx $$

The first thing I see is that $\int_{k/n}^{k/n+1/n}f(x)dx$ looks similar to $Av_{1/n}f(x)$ where $Av_{h}=\frac{1}{h}\int_x^{x+h}f$, but I am not sure how to use that (or if it's helpful at all) since we don't have $x$ in the bounds of the integral. Other than that, I am not sure where to begin with this so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

By the triangle inequality that LHS $\leq$ RHS is obvious.
For the opposite inequality, choose $g,h$ so that $f=g+h$, where $g$ is continuous and $||h||_1 < \epsilon$.
Then 
$$
\sum_{k=-n^2}^{n^2} \left| \int_{k/n}^{(k+1)/n} f(x)dx \right|
=\sum_{k=-n^2}^{n^2} \left| \int_{k/n}^{(k+1)/n} (g(x) + h(x))dx \right|
$$
$$
\geq\sum_{k=-n^2}^{n^2}
\left[ \left| \int_{k/n}^{(k+1)/n} g(x)dx\right| -  \int_{k/n}^{(k+1)/n} |h(x)|dx \right]
$$
$$
\geq\sum_{k=-n^2}^{n^2} \left[\left| \int_{k/n}^{(k+1)/n} g(x)dx\right| \right]-  \epsilon.
$$
If the result holds for $g$, then taking the limsup in $n$ of both sides and sending $\epsilon \to 0$ finishes the claim. Thus it suffices to show the result holds for continuous functions. This is easy to show, so I'll leave it to you.